# How to insert struct, map type in Apache Hudi

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-hudi

I see the official document, there are no samples about inserting complex types like struct and map.

So, what's the grammar?

My table definition:

```sql
spark-sql> desc struct_map;
_hoodie_commit_time     string  NULL
_hoodie_commit_seqno    string  NULL
_hoodie_record_key      string  NULL
_hoodie_partition_path  string  NULL
_hoodie_file_name       string  NULL
uuid    int     NULL
col1    struct<col11:int,col12:struct<col121:int>>      NULL
col2    map<string,int> NULL
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hudi uses the spark SQL syntax, so you can use its documentation (examples from databricks doc: [ex1](https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/data-types/struct-type.html), [ex2](https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/data-types/map-type.html))

For map, you can use the func map('<field 1>', val1, '<field 2>', val2, ...), and for struct, you can use the func struct(val1, val2, ...) or named_struct('<field 1>', val1, '<field 2>', val2)

```sql
INSERT INTO struct_map VALUES
(0, struct(0, struct(0)), map('key1', 1, 'key2', 2));
INSERT INTO struct_map VALUES
(0, named_struct('col11', 0, 'col12', struct('col121', 0)), map('key1', 1, 'key2', 2));
```